# Sublime Text: Clear Console

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a built in function that clears the console in sublime text? I found two posts in the sublime forum without any answers. The latest post was in 2013.

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8609&p=35587&hilit=clear+console#p35587
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2356&p=48866&hilit=clear+console#p48866

Comment: I usually clear the console by moving cursor to top (ctrl+home or cmd+home), select all (ctrl+A or cmd+A), and delete. I've only recently started using Sublime Text, so I'm not familiar with programming for it, but perhaps there's a way to turn three keystrokes or commands into a single method call that could then be bound to a different keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "clear" it in the traditional sense, but you can always use **print('\n' * 50)** which will generate 50 blank lines and have the same appearance as a cleared console.